# C# how to pointers

Tags: c#, pointers

using an "API" where the function is defined like

```
int foo(char *arg1, short *arg2);
```

so I did this

```
[DllImport(@"path\file.dll")]
public static extern int foo(ref string arg1, ref int arg2);
```

but when I call foo

```
int ret_val = foo(ref arg1, ref arg2);
```

It throws a `System.AccessViolationException`

If i implement arg1 without ref keyword, just value-type, no Exception is thrown.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I have to define that pointers in C#?

Comment: A string is already a reference, you do not have char** but note that System.String is wchar_t, not char. Check docs about marshaling

Comment: Give a try with  : public static extern int foo(StringBuilder arg1, StringBuilder arg2);

Comment: StringBuilder is working, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)